# import Wheel file dependency without using absolute path

Tags: python, import, python-import, aws-glue, python-wheel

I have successfully created a wheel file. Below is the structure of my project:

```
myproject
├── package
|    ├──api
|    |   ├── __init__.py
|    |   ├── main.py
|    |
|    ├──utils
|        ├── __init__.py
|        ├── helpers.py
|        ├── config.yml
├── setup.py
```

I am using this wheel file in AWS glue job. Below is the code that I am using to import the dependencies from the wheel file:

```
from package.utils import helpers
#some python code here
```

Everything is working fine till here, But my requirement is to "import helpers" directly without specifying "from package.utils" or the path of python class. I want to use helpers class like below:

```
import helpers
#some code here
```

Kindly suggest how I can achieve this.

Comment: You want to do that so that you can use the functions/classes that are inside helpers directly without using helpers.<func_name>??

Comment: I just don't want to give the absolute path like from package.utils.

Comment: from package.utils.helpers import * will help you?

Comment: what does your setup file look like?